# Entity Framework 4: Saving one to many entities doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4, entity-relationship

Here is a common scenario 
I Have these Entity
**User** 
UserId
UserName 
...


**UserQuestion** 
UserQID 
UserID 
UserQuestion 
UserAnswer

One user can Have many question, but one question is attached to one user.
In my example, I create 3 Empty entities (UserQuestion). Then I attache these question on the user.

In the view, for each question, answer textbox, I Use ElementAt to specify each of the UserQuestion Entity.

Why I cannot save these 3 questions

**In the Controller**

```
public ActionResult ChooseQuestion()
{
    IUserRepository repUser = new UserRepository(EntityFactory.GetEntity());
    User usr = repUser.GetUserByID(Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]));
    usr.UserQuestions.Add(new UserQuestion());
    usr.UserQuestions.Add(new UserQuestion());
    usr.UserQuestions.Add(new UserQuestion());
    var ViewModel = new UsrViewModel()
                    {
                        UserInfo = usr
                    };   
    return View(ViewModel);

}

[HttpPost]
public void ChooseQuestion(User UserInfo)
{
    UpdateModel(User, "UserInfo");
    EntityFactory.GetEntity().SaveChanges();
}
```

**In my View**

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserInfo.UserName)%>
...
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserInfo.LastName%>
...
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserInfo.UserPassword%>
..
<h2>Question Creation</h2>
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserInfo.UserQuestions.ElementAt(0).UserQuestion)%>
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserInfo.UserQuestions.ElementAt(0).UserAnswer)%>

<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserInfo.UserQuestions.ElementAt(1).UserQuestion)%>
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserInfo.UserQuestions.ElementAt(1).UserAnswer)%>

<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserInfo.UserQuestions.ElementAt(2).UserQuestion)%>
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserInfo.UserQuestions.ElementAt(2).UserAnswer)%>
```

3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [Phil Haack's post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) you should just have sequential number in your name attribute like so:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserInfo.UserQuestions.ElementAt(0).UserQuestion, new {name="UserInfo.UserQuestion0.UserQuestion} )%>
```

Normally the built-in HtmlHelper.TextboxFor method will do the name attribute correctly if it is in a for loop.

As I'm not near my VS now I can't try this magic out for myself, but you might want to check Phil's article if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks BorisCallens, This is EXACTLY what i was looking for. Phil Haack Post is just what I need. THANKS . I search for a while and never find the answer. A+++ for the answer here. Thanks to the other people how try to help me,It's really appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could be of service ;)

Answer (score 0):

not sure exactly what you are looking for:

it seems you are missing a question table:

```
question
---------
question_id
question_text
```

then link that to the user

```
user_question
--------------
user_id
question_id
answer
```

Comment: No , the question can be associate with only one user

Answer (score 0):

The error is that

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserInfo.UserQuestions.ElementAt(0).UserQuestion)%>
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserInfo.UserQuestions.ElementAt(1).UserQuestion)%>
```

Generates HTML code:

```
<input id="UserQuestion" name="UserQuestion" type="text" value="UserQuestion" />
<input id="UserQuestion" name="UserQuestion" type="text" value="UserQuestion" />
```

As you can see: there are inputs with same `id`s, which is forbidden. So when you post data back to the controller only one value is sent via PostParameters: UserQuestion=, no indexes, no prefixes, no `UserQuestions.UserQuestion[0]`.

For more digging into alike question, I suggest using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and intercept traffic sent by your forms.

Second problem with your code is that you are using `UpdateModel(User, "UserInfo")` and UserInfo parameter (of type User). (BTW: how does this code compiles? By all means it shouldn't).
It's better to use `FormCollection` as parameter when you call `UpdateModel`. Because in your case variable `UserInfo` is already updated.
As for me, you are doing odd things, trying to edit whole collection.

Comment: Ok Forgot about the UpdateModel you absolutely right. But now, What i'm suposed to put in the textboxFor <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserInfo.UserQuestions.ElementAt(0).UserQuestion)%>   Replace by ....

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code as such:

```
<h2>Question Creation</h2>
<% for (int i = 0; i < Model.UserInfo.UserQuestions.Count; i++) { %>
  <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserInfo.UserQuestions[i].UserQuestion)%>
  <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserInfo.UserQuestions[i].UserAnswer)%>
<% } %>
```

then at least your code is dry.

[HttpPost]
public void ChooseQuestion(User UserInfo)
{
    IUserRepository repUser = new UserRepository(EntityFactory.GetEntity());
    User usr = repUser.GetUserByID(Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]));

```
UpdateModel(usr);
EntityFactory.GetEntity().SaveChanges();
```

}

depending on if questions exist or not this should work.
the UserInfo object should contain your questions, you could `foreach` them and add them manualy as well.

Comment: I , thanks for your reply. But the main problem here, is I Cannot do model.UserInfo.UserQuestions[i] .. This is not a table... It's a entitycollection of UserQuestions. That's mean I'll not be able to specify directly an index on the table like [i]. The only way I can specify it, it with elementAt(i)... Why.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running SaveChanges on a new entity that does not contain any changes rarther than one that contains the information updated by the client.